# seo difference between a nav or just a ul

Tags: html, seo

If I use a just a `ul` for my navigation menu, will that be worse with regards to SEO than a `nav` element?

I would rather use just a `ul` as I don't need to shiv it for older browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SEO is too broad a concept to worry about using `UL` or `NAV`.

What you main aim needs to be is **Semantics**.

So basically, enclosing the `UL` within a `NAV` gives more meaning to your code and thus *appreciated* by good search engines

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's worse than using the semantically clearer element... with `<nav>` the search engines could theoretically get to know more about your site's structure.

However, a proper sitemap is likely going to do as well.